# AJAX display result wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, wordpress

Good morning, everyone,

I have a new problem with my script. I cannot display the values of my SQL request.

My game. php script that acts as a view:

```html
<div id="chat" class="hidden">
<p id="zone_list_player" ></p>
<p>blablablabla </p>
<span id="points_action"></span>
</div>
```

Then come my file with my AJAX request:

```js
function btn_display_urgent(html){
$.ajax({url: '../../wp-content/plugins/game_plugin/process_general.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {info: 'display_urgent', input: $input},
    success: function(html) {
        console.log("OK");
        console.log($input);
        $('#zone_list_player').html(html);
    }
});
}
```

And to finish my PHP file that processes requests and makes a select in my database:

```html
function display_urgent(){
    try {
        echo "blabla1";
        $db = openBDD(); //fonction pour ouvrir acces BDD

        $bdd = $db->prepare("SELECT from_mail FROM test_insert");
        $bdd->execute;
        echo "blabla2";
        $result = $bdd->fetch(); // retourne sous forme d'un tableau la PREMIERE valeur.
        echo "blabla3";
        
        return $result["chat"];
       
        
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I've tried many things but my lack of experience plays in my defaveur.
My echo "blabla" is displayed where I want in my view. But I can't display the result of my SELECT. I'm definitely forgetting something, but I don't know what. If a mae genereuse could direct me or give me some advice, I would be grateful to her ad vitam aeternam.

Thanks to all of you, I'll stay available if needed, good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **wp_ajax_** hook for ajax in wordpress.
Here are some example of using ajax in wp.

Reference sites :

https://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

https://shellcreeper.com/wp-ajax-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to help myself, here is the sql request part called by AJAX:

```html
function display_urgent(){
    try {
        
        
        $db = openBDD(); //fonction pour ouvrir acces BDD

        $bdd = $db->query("SELECT from_mail, subject, recei, preview FROM test_insert ORDER BY recei DESC");
        $bdd->execute;
        
        $result = $bdd->fetch(); // retourne sous forme d'un tableau la PREMIERE valeur.
        foreach($bdd as $result){
        
        
   

 echo nl2br($result[from_mail] ."\n". $result[subject] ."\n". $result[recei] ."\n". $result[preview]."\n");

        
        
        }
        
        
       
        
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo"pas bon";
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```